# If I use '\b' and '\n' together,why doesn't it delete last character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I tried to print a line and after two seconds,delete the last square and go to next line.But,if I use '\b\n' together,it doesn't delete the last square but,it goes to next line.Why doesn't it work?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from time import sleep
import sys
def color():
       s=sys.stdout
       s.write('\033[32m\u25a0\033[m'*10)
       s.flush()
       sleep(2)
       s.write('\b\n')
       s.flush()
color()
```

Comment: `\b` does not delete anything, it moves the cursor one step left.

Comment: Should your output print only 9 squares? If yes, I dont see any issues.It works fine

Comment: try it on terminal

Comment: What you want is the *erase sequence* `'\b \b'`, which move the cursor one step left, erase the current position with a space, and steps back again.

Comment: What is the difference between '\b' and '\b \b' ?

Comment: `'\b'` only moves the cursor back. By doing `'\b '` you are moving the cursor back and replace the character with a space. And then doing `'\b \b'` will replace the character and position the cursor before it.

Comment: then,backspace use like arrow keys?

Comment: `\b` is just a byte. A terminal can "display" that byte however it wants, but *conventionally* it is taken as an instruction to move the cursor to the left (that was the reason for including such a definition in ASCII). It's up to the terminal whether to overwrite or superimpose the next character on top of the character already at that cursor position.

Comment: Likewise, `\n` is not even a byte, but an abstraction over the idea of a line ending, which consists of a platform-dependent byte (or pair of bytes, in the case of DOS/Windows). But again, the general interpretation of the line ending by a terminal is to simply move the cursor to the beginning of the following line.

Comment: The "right" way to remove a character is to use `seek` to move the file pointer back one spot. However, `sys.stdout` is not generally seekable. There's no guarantee that you can remove or overwrite a value that has already been written. That's like accidentally dropping your phone in the garbage, but hoping to get it back by dropping something else in.